# Social APIs not working because of cURL and SSL

Tags: php, curl, ssl, social-networking, hybridauth

I'm using a social authentication plugin called HybridAuth. When using it on my shared server but now I have upgraded to a VPS running IIS 7.

I read that I needed to instal cURL with SSL and when running `phpinfo()`, all is showing to be configured properly.

However, I am getting errors when trying to connect to the social networks:

`Invalid or no certificate authority found, using bundled information`

`Error: Authentification failed! Twitter returned an error. 401 Unauthorized.`

How can I fix this?

Comment: curl doesn't include any CA certs by default anymore, so it cannot verify ANY ssl certs as valid until you provide the public CA stuff for the particular cert you're trying to validate against.

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/79f1db02-cef1-4a54-ae99-080ff4729393/is-there-a-problem-with-curl-on-azure

Answer (score 0):

Try telling curl not to check for such things

```
curl_setopt_array ( $curl_instance , array(
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
) );
```